# PHP class scope

Tags: php, oop, class, scope

I have several classes in an application that I am currently building, and I want to have one access some of the other's member functions but i can't seem to do it.

The first class is called MySQLDB:

```
class MySQLDB{
public $connection;

function __construct(){
//connects to database
}

function login($username, $password){
//queries database...
}
}
```

Then I have a class called Session:

```
class Session{
//variables
//constructor

function processlogin($username, $password){
$database->login($username, $password);
}
```

Then after this I have two class declarations:

```
$database = new MySQLDB();
$session = new Session();
```

No matter where i put these statements in relation to the classes I still get the same error:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: database in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\cmu\include\session.php on line 52
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function login() on a non-object in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\cmu\include\session.php on line 52
```

I have seen some suggestions that would suggest putting the new database object inside the Session class declaration but I want to avoid doing so because I use the database class several other places in the code and I don't want to open up multiple connections to the database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

since you want to have acces on a globally set variable, you can either gain access to it with `global`:

```
function processlogin($username, $password){
    global $database;
    $database->login($username, $password);
}
```

or use the variable as a parameter for the contructor and remember the database object reference in the class `Session`:

```
class Session{

    private $database;

    function __construct($database){
        $this->$database = $database;
    }

    function processlogin($username, $password){
        $this->database->login($username, $password);
    }

}
```

and then you call:

```
$database = new MySQLDB();
$session = new Session($database);
```

this comes in handy, if you use more functions afterwords, that also need access to the database object.

Comment: Thanks I just used the `global $database` statement and it worked just fine for now. I plan on trying the second method when I get a chance but I want to check with you to make sure that it references the object and does not create a duplicate.

Comment: I needed smth similar for my latest project and I realized I was running about 10 instances of the db for the same thing. It may be a problem if  the `MySQLDB` instance needs to be  used by other classes simultaneously, because the `$database` object in the `Session` instance will not refer to the same instance. So if you  alter the object from another place, that modification will not be visible to your class. Say you want to do smth like : `$database->setEncoding('utf-8');`; then you will have to do the exact same thing for your Session db : `$session->database->setEncoding('utf-8')`

Comment: Down use `global` in a class. it totally destoys the encapsulation of your class. **Only use method 2** in this answer

Answer (score 4):

you could pass a reference to the `MySQLDB` instance in the `Session` constructor.

```
class Session{
    public $db;

    function __construct(&$db=null){
        if($db == null)
            $this->db = new MySQLDB();
        else
            $this->db = $db;
    }
    // ....
}

$database = new MySQLDB();
$session = new Session($database);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are creating two global variables. If you're doing such thing, you need to declare variables you want to use in function with "global" keyword:

```
function processlogin($username, $password){
global $database;
$database->login($username, $password);
}
```

Despite this will work, I highly recommend reading about Dependecy Injection mechanism in which you'd pass `$database` variable as a parameter to processlogin() method, or set it as a private member of that class in constructor / setter. That way database connection will be interchangeable and you'll get more flexibility in your code.

Answer (score 2):

`$database` is not defined inside `processlogin` nor passed as parameter, hence the function has no access to it.

You could pass it as constructor parameter to `Session`:

```
class Session {
    private $db;

    public function __construct($database) {
        $this->db = $database;

    public function processlogin($username, $password){
        $this->$db->login($username, $password);
    }
}

$database = new MySQLDB();
$session = new Session($database);
```

Comment: why not create a parent class that has child classes and then make a call to the parent or child class?

Comment: @Gerald: You mean `Session` should be a child of `MySQLDB`? Inheritance expresses a *is-a* relationship, but a *Session* is not a *MySQLDB*. A session *uses* a DB, which is what composition is for. It just makes more sense semantically, but of course you can do whatever you want ;)